# jwysiwyg: Don't clone certain attributes when appending a new paragraph?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jwysiwyg

When adding a new paragraph by hitting enter in jwysiwyg, the new paragraph automatically has the previous paragraph's attributes assigned to it.

Is there a way to disallow the cloning of certain attributes into newly inserted elements? I looked in the source of jwysiwyg but am not having much luck finding where the elements get cloned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CKeditor instead. It's definitely bigger, probably more than I need, but it provided some other things we needed for this project as well.

However, I had the same problem in CKeditor. All attributes except `id` were cloned, including my custom attribute.

In CK, I was able to circumvent this by adding `node.removeAttribute( 'myattrib', false );` at line 117 of `/ckeditor/_source/core/dom/node.js`